# How to make animations for two objects?

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

I have a sword and then a slash effect thing that trails behind it. The effect thing looks like [this](http://images.gameskinny.com/gameskinny/26c1ccf19754bee8bfa188f9683e5c34.jpg). I'm using the animation data tab in the NLA editor to create different animations for the sword such as holding, swinging left, swinging down, etc. I want the slash effect thing to not be there unless the sword is actually being swung, and like get bigger until the slash finishes and then shrink back to nothing. The problem is, when I insert keyframes for the effect thing, which is a separate object from the sword, they apply to all animations, so the effect thing will be in the same place whether the sword is being held or swung. Is there a way to associate the keyframes of the sword effect with the actual sword?

[Pictures of problem.](https://imgur.com/a/0UpcF) If I could just get the keys for plane.001 and cube to be  seperate from each other, I would be fine.

Comment: have you tried using constraints on the slash to follow the sword and just animate hid/show and scale

Comment: So I set a constraint, and the effect follows the sword now, but when I set both the effect object and the sword object to the same animation, like "swing left," it will apply the keyframes of "swing left" to the effect object as well, which will end up shrinking and moving the effect. I assume that there isnt a way give different objects different keyframes for the same animation, but my problem is that if I make two animations, one for each object, for every actual animation, I won't know how to properly import into Unity so that the animations are associated with each other.

Comment: what constraint did you use , also if you can upload a sample file that we can experiment with it would be helpful

Comment: I used the "child of" restraint. Im not sure how to upload a sample file, although I have one ready, but for now ill upload pictures.

Comment: I'm glade you have solved it, if you can add more details ( steps ) in your answer so others can benefit from your experience , also you accept your answer to indicate that the question is closed

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You just have to use [armatures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9iL1hmJXrI). What this means is:

- create an armature from the create menu <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
- position the bones in the Edit mode.
- switch to the pose mode, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> click on each object and its corresponding bone.
- press <kbd>P</kbd> to connect them using "bone" from the parent menu.
- finally animate the entire armature.

Comment: I added a step by step description, which chebhou kindly cleaned up for me.